# NodeJS installation to jenkins : npm not found

Tags: node.js, jenkins

Maybe someone can tell me what I missed installing nodeJS to jenkins, because when I want to execute shell script `npm update` I get error `npm: not found`.

I installed jenkins nodejs plugin then added installer:
 [image]

After I created job with prams:

[image]

What I need to do more, to have accessible npm in any jenkins job?

Comment: Just for anyone having this issue; somehow edit/saving the job solved this issue for me (twice in a few months now).

Answer (score 2):

It works for me. The only difference is that where you have a text box that reads "0.12.7", I have a popup menu that reads "Node.js 0.12.7". Maybe something has gone wrong and you should delete the installer and add it back?

Comment: I do not know why, but after night it started working for me too, maybe jenkins machine was restarted...

Answer (score 0):

#### Windows users, did you restart?

Do keep in mind that you need to restart active processes after installing npm.
During installation the folder of your `npm.cmd` is added to the `PATH` variable. However, active applications don't refresh their `PATH` variable automatically. That also holds for your active Jenkins service (and its child processes). They are still running with an old version of your `PATH` variable.

In other words, you need to **restart the Jenkins service** (or restart your entire system). Once restarted, Jenkins will have an updated `PATH` variable, and it will be able to find the `npm.cmd` processes and others.

#### What's wrong with using absolute paths?

Using the full path is not a solid solution. A `package.json` file can contain references to other cli processes (e.g. `node`, `ng`, `react-scripts`, `npm-run-all`,  ...). You will probably have similar issues there. There is no way to keep up and reference all of them with full paths.